# How to avoid duplicating in Android Room

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I want to create an app that stores the names of scooters, but when I search name, I am getting duplicates, I am using Room for Android, here is my code. Anyone please help me, thanks.

*POJO Class*

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int id;

@ColumnInfo(name = "battery")
private String battery;

@ColumnInfo(name = "code")
private String birdCode;

@ColumnInfo(name = "latitude")
private double lat;

@ColumnInfo(name = "longitude")
private double lng;
```

*Dao Interface*

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM BirdsRoom" )
List<BirdsRoom> getCachedBirds();

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertBirds(BirdsRoom... birdsRoom);
```

*How I insert data*

```
Birds birds = response.body().getBirdsList().get(i);
BirdLocation birdLocation = birds.birdLocation;
BirdLocation location = birds.birdLocation;
BirdsRoom birdsRoom = new BirdsRoom(birds.getCode(),birds.getBatteryLevel(), 
birdLocation.getLat(), birdLocation.getLng());
birdsDatabase.getUserDao().insertBirds(birdsRoom);
```

Comment: share code about how you store data by calling `insertBirds`.

Comment: I have shared the code, Birds class and BirdLocation class is my retrofit POJO class, BirdsRoom is entitiy class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be  battery and code unique in your BirdsRoom to set annotation like below

```
@Entity(indices = {@Index(value = {"battery", "code"}, unique = true)})
public class BirdsRoom {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int id;

@ColumnInfo(name = "battery")
private String battery;

@ColumnInfo(name = "code")
private String birdCode;

@ColumnInfo(name = "latitude")
private double lat;

@ColumnInfo(name = "longitude")
private double lng;
```

Comment: It gave me this error:   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: BirdsRoom.code (code 2067)

Comment: When your BirdsRoom exists allready and you change BirdsRoom, you have to migrate database or uninstal app and install again with new BirdsRoom

Comment: No it doesn't help, first run is successfull, but second run is give mentioned error

Comment: Thanks I have added (onConfict = ConflictStrategy.REPLACE) it helped, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the values duplicate, you can add incides annotation it likewise;

```
@Entity(
   tableName = "birds",
   indices = [
       Index("battery", unique = true),
       Index("code", unique = true)
   ]
)
```